# Capping the value of RGB to 255

Tags: c, cs50

I'm working on CS50 pset4 sepia filter and trying to cap the RGB value at 255 with my `cap` function, but it seems still doesn't working. Can anyone advice me where to look and how to fix without spoiling my academic honesty commitment?

I've used `unsigned char` because ide gives error otherwise. Also doesn't accept `BYTE` as a type. I've tried to cast it to integer but it gives error too. Maybe my casting was not correctly. I'll appreciate if you want to add a brief explaination for me to understand my mistake so I could be more efficient in my future code regarding this issue.

This my ap function:

```
unsigned char cap(unsigned char a)
{
    if (a > 255)
    {
        a = 255;
    }
    return a;
}
```

and this the code in sepia function (in the nested loops)

```
unsigned char x = image[i][j].rgbtRed;
unsigned char y = image[i][j].rgbtGreen;
unsigned char z = image[i][j].rgbtBlue;

image[i][j].rgbtRed = cap(round(x * 0.393 + y * 0.769 + z * 0.189));
image[i][j].rgbtGreen = cap(round(x * 0.349 + y * 0.686 + z * 0.168));
image[i][j].rgbtBlue = cap(round(x * 0.272 + y * 0.534 + z * 0.131));
```

Comment: _"I've used unsigned char because ide gives error otherwise"_. What exactly is _"otherwise"_?

Comment: Understanding the numerical limits of the types used is a must. `unsigned char` can never be larger than 255, so checking if it is larger than that is senseless. It will however wrap-around to zero in case you go beyond 255.

Comment: Note: do not cap colours. If they are larger then 255, factor them down, so that you do not change hue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`unsigned char` as the type of input parameter excludes values > 255 (if bytes are 8 bits as they commonly are). Just make your function accept an `int` or `float` or `double`. Likewise you should probably clamp negative numbers to zero, though they won't occur in *this* calculation but might occur in some other.

```
unsigned char cap(int a)
{
    if (a > 255) {
        return 255;
    }
    if (a < 0) {
        return 0;
    }

    return a;
}
```

---

As for `BYTE`, you declare a typedef:

```
typedef unsigned char BYTE;
```

and use `BYTE` thereafter.

Comment: Thanks a lot after changing it to (int a) it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Change the `cap()` function to be more like:

```
unsigned char cap(unsigned int a)
```

The problem is that the C compiler truncates "larger than 255" values to make them fit in an `unsigned char` when trying to pass the values to the `cap()` function.

Alternatively; use `fmin()` or `fminf()` instead (e.g. `image[i][j].rgbtBlue = fmin(round(x * 0.272 + y * 0.534 + z * 0.131), 255.0);`).

Comment: I'm not sure where the truncation happens when try to pass the argument to the funcion. Parameters are passed as integer, never as char (this is a difference between C and C++). So I expect truncation happens when the function use the value.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi: For `unsigned char cap(unsigned char a)` the compiler has to make it behave like `unsigned char` (before it passes it); so you might (or might not, depending on compiler, etc) end up with is code to converting to some kind of larger integer (because that's typically cheap/supported by CPU efficiently), followed by a mask (like `a = a & 0xFF`) to force it to behave like an `unsigned char`, followed by passing it in whatever way the ABI says (if the ABI is relevant), which might mean passing it in a 64-bit register (even if `int` is 32 bits).